# unable to pass id in the dropdown menu of my navigation bar

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to pass id in the dropdown menu of my navigation bar. this is my code

```
 <?php
echo $date=$_GET['id'];echo"</br>";
  echo $d=$_GET['id1'];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("vas1",$con);
?>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
<ul id="nav" class="drop">



   <li><a href='calls1.php?id=$date&id1=$d' class="style1">View Trends</a></li>
```

$date and $d are correctly echoed passed from my previous page but when i click on 'View Trends' it do open the calls1.php but the ids are not passed. this is the url of calls1.php to show how its passed

```
http://localhost/vas1/calls1.php?id=$date&id1=$d
```

but it should be like:

```
http://localhost/vas1/calls1.php?id=20121110&id1=November%202012
```

what should i do.... m hell confused here... please someone guide me

Comment: please anyone help me out... if it wont work , i can't proceed forward

Answer (score 0):

Open the PHP tags. You cannot echo PHP variables in HTML without opening the PHP tag.

```
<li><a href='calls1.php?id=<?=$date;?>&id1=<?= $d; ?>' class="style1">View Trends</a></li>
```

Place this on top of calls1.php,

```
 <?php
 $date=$_GET['id'];echo"</br>";
$d=$_GET['id1'];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("vas1",$con);
?>
```

Comment: its still not working.. now the url is like: http://localhost/vas1/calls1.php?id=&id1=

Comment: the file that opens when I click 'View Trends' and I have pasted the url also of calls1.php in my question... please help me to get this id and id1 on calls1.php

Comment: Shorttags might be disabled: try to use <?php echo $d; ?>

Comment: i hv used it as <?php echo $d; ?> but still no output... please anyone help me out... i am badly struck in it